# Can I hardwire a household fan with a 2.5A "fused" plug?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

I am wanting to install a wall mounted household fan made by AEROWAY model VIVI . . . I have installed a junction box and am wondering if I can hardwire direct to household circuit with 20A breaker by simply bypassing the plug . . . I didn't notice the plug was fused until I had already installed and pre-wired the junction box (and cut the required hole in wall etc.)

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: There are a few issues involved. There are plenty of products (especially kitchen appliances) that can be connected both ways. The ideal setup would be to mount the fan base directly on a junction box, just like a hardwired lighting fixture. However, the web site gives very little information. I suggest contacting Aeroway.

Comment: Thanks for the response manassehkatz . . . . In essence that is exactly what I'm doing . . . My only question I guess is WHY is there a fuse on the plug, is it designed to be MORE aggressive in breaking the circuit because of a history of the fan motors overheating or are their places that require it and as a means to save money they put one on ALL their cords . . . .

Answer (score 1):

Greg in the states a UL listed device can not be modified this voids the listing. Removing the fused plug voids the UL listing for a 15 or 20 amp circuit, as a second code violation you said drilling a hole in the wall cordage is not allowed to pass through walls so I believe this would be a second failure point. There are fixtures both fans and lights designed to be hardwired theses usually require a junction box with a cord grip for the type of cord being used but removal of the fuse is not safe by itself.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I think the best solution will be to find another unit which is designed to be hardwired . . . I'm installing this in my Daughters home and based on your expertise would not feel comfortable doing it as planned . . . My bigger hurdle now is having my Daughter select an acceptable style of fan that will have the "right" look . . . LOL . . . Thanks again and Stay safe!